# How to work on one line of a file at a time in python

Tags: python, excel, loops, file

**edited based on @Boendal answer.**

I've been working on a script and when I thought everything works great turns out it doesn't and I can't find a solution or even figure out why my logic is not working. I'm pretty new to python so I'm sorry if it's trivial but I would like to see it work. Here is the problem:
I have a text file generated by another script that contains lines with numbers combinations, like this:

```
(1800, 2100, 2600, 1500, 900, 3700)
(1800, 2100, 2600, 900, 800, 3700)
(1800, 2100, 1500, 900, 800, 3700)
(1800, 2600, 1500, 900, 800, 3700)
(1800, 2100, 2600, 1500, 900, 3700)
(1800, 2100, 2600, 900, 800, 3700)
(1800, 2100, 1500, 900, 800, 3700)
(1800, 2100, 2600, 1500, 900, 3700)
(1800, 2100, 2600, 900, 800, 3700)
(1800, 2600, 1500, 900, 800, 3700)
(1800, 2100, 2600, 1500, 900, 3700)
(1800, 2100, 1500, 900, 800, 3700)
(1800, 2600, 1500, 900, 800, 3700)
```

and in another script that uses this file as an input I want to go line by line, work on each line and move to the other. I thought about removing a line after I'm done with it(so I always work on the same line) but that seems even more complicated so I decided to simply use a for loop. Here is a code:

```
(...)
for i, line in enumerate(lines):  
        i=i+1
        line_number = literal_eval(line)

        if "1800" in line_number:
            cell1800_a = sheet.cell(row=i,column=27)
            cell1800_a.value = number
            cell1800_b = sheet.cell(row=i,column=29)
            cell1800_b.value = number
            stf_18 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=50)
            stf_18.value = "radio7"
            stf18Q = sheet.cell(row=i,column=51)
            if number in range (1,2):
                stf18Q.value = 1
            elif number in range (3,4):
                stf18Q.value = 2
            elif number in range (5,6):
               stf18Q.value = 3
            if question1 == "y":
                cell1800_2g = sheet.cell(row=i,column=26)
                cell1800_2g.value = number

        if "2100" in line_number:
            cell2100_a = sheet.cell(row=i,column=25)
            cell2100_a.value = number
            stf18 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=52)
            stf18.value = "radio7"
            stf18Q = sheet.cell(row=i,column=53)
            if number in range (1,2):
                stf18Q.value = 1
            elif number in range (3,4):
                stf18Q.value = 2
            elif number in range (5,6):
                stf18Q.value = 3
            if question2 == "y":
                cell2100_b = sheet.cell(row=i,column=24)
                cell2100_b.value = number

        if "2600" in line_number:
            cell2600 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=30)
            cell2600.value = number
            stf26 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=54)
            stf26.value = "radio6"
            stf26Q = sheet.cell(row=i,column=55)
            if number in range (1,2):
                stf26Q.value = 1
            elif number in range (3,4):
                stf26Q.value = 2
            elif number in range (5,6):
                stf26Q.value = 3

        if "1500" in line_number:
            cell1500 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=34)
            cell1500.value = number
            stf15 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=48)
            stf15.value = "radio5"
            stf15Q = sheet.cell(row=i,column=49)
            stf15Q.value = number

        if "900 "in line_number:
            if question1 == "y":
                cell900_A = sheet.cell(row=i,column=31)
                cell900_A.value = number
                stf9 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=46)
                stf9.value = "radio4"
                stf9Q = sheet.cell(row=i,column=47)
                stf9Q.value = number
            if  question2 == "y":
                cell900_B = sheet.cell(row=i,column=32)
                cell900_B.value = number
                stf9 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=46)
                stf9.value = "radio3"
                stf9Q = sheet.cell(row=i,column=47)
                stf9Q.value = number

        if "800" in line_number:
            cell800 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=33)
            cell800.value = number
            stf8 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=44)
            stf8.value = "radio2"
            stf8Q = sheet.cell(row=i,column=45)
            stf8.value = number

        if "3700" in line_number:
            cell3700 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=40)
            cell3700.value = number
            stfa = sheet.cell(row=i,column=87)
            stfa.value = "radio1"
            stfaq = sheet.cell(row=i,column=88)
            stfaq.value = number



          (...)
```

**basically what I need to do** is open a file, read one line and check what numbers it contains and if it contains specific number put a value in an excel cell and move to the next line. Everything works other than actually looping through the lines... The code reads just one line and puts the same values in all the cells even though each line contains different combination of the numbers.

I would be very grateful if you can help me solve it, because I've been staring at it for hours now and I'm really not seeing it (and I'm pretty sure it's a simple logic error)

Comment: The iteration through your lines is correct, although there are easier ways to achieve it. Are you aware that all the numbers you are looking for are present in all the lines you provided as sample code? Apart from that please be aware that you are overwriting `cell2100_a` for each `i` in the row. Maybe you are looking for a way to "append" the data instead?

Comment: Where did you pass the value of `number` to the variable `number`

Comment: And you can iterate directly using your list (here is each read line)

Comment: @offeltoffel most of them yes, there are just small differences. First line for example (1800, 2100, 2600, 1500, 900, 3700) contains 1500 which second line doesn't and instead has 800. (1800, 2100, 2600, 900, 800, 3700). Anyway if the code is correct this means my logic doesn't work somewhere else here... when you say I overwrite cell2100_a (I'm not aware) is it only this one or actually all of them?

Comment: @Clément number and all other variables are in other parts of the code hence the (...) on both ends of the code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you want to do is something like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open ("numbers.txt") as inFile:
    lines = inFile.readlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines,1): #start with 1 because excel row start with index = 1
        line_number = literal_eval(line)
        if 1800 in line_number :
            cell1800_a = sheet.cell(row=i,column=27)
            cell1800_a.value = number
            cell1800_b = sheet.cell(row=i,column=29)
            cell1800_b.value = number

        if 2100 in line_number:
            cell2100_a = sheet.cell(row=i,column=25)
            cell2100_a.value = number

        if 2600 in line_number :
            cell2600 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=30)
            cell2600.value = number

        if 1500 in line_number :
            cell1500 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=34)
            cell1500.value = number

        if 800 in line_number :
            cell800 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=33)
            cell800.value = number

        if 3700 in line_number :
            cell3700 = sheet.cell(row=i,column=40)
            cell3700.value = number
```

What I changed:

1. I evaled the input string as a tuple. The reason is that if you are looking for the String 800 in a string for example `(1800, 2100, 2600, 1500, 900, 3700)` you will find a match because 1800 has 800 in it. So to avoid this I evaled it and now I'm looking into a tuple of number of the correct number so it would only match if the number 800 is in the tuple which is not the case in the example above.
2. You had 2 for loops and the 2nd for loop was unnecessary. I think you want that each line of your txt file correspondend to the line in your excel file. But with your 2nd for loop you overwrite every match that happens before and in the worst case you have an excel full with the same value evaluated for only the last line. 
   Basically you only have to write the value once for each line not multiple times.
3. `else` and `pass` part was unecessary and I deleted it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped but only kind of which made it even weirder tbh. Now it works but only for 800... also there was an issue with i starting with 0 and excel cells obviously start with one but that was an easy fix. Do you maybe have any idea why it only works for 800 right now?

Comment: hmm that doesn't really make sense... can you show me your updated code? @Aleksa

Comment: Hi! Updated my original question. Sorry the code is more complex, I don't think it matters for the actual program since the value 1500 and 800 have the same logic just different values and 1500 doesn't work

Comment: @Aleksa I'm not sure why 800 is working but for me 800 shouldn't even work. You are trying to find `"1800"`(a String) in a list of int. Remove all `"` from the number you are checking and try again (see my solution as you see I removed the `"` around the numbers).

Comment: yeah I tried without them as well and gives me the same result :P

Comment: @Aleksa can you print line_number and show me the output? and you have to remove `"` for sure.

Comment: It works now! There was an excel issue and it made it weird but I've changed it and it worked! thank you so much!!!!